# How to create two database copies in two users from same dump file

Tags: oracle, import

I have a database dump file with me, I need to make two copies of the database using the same dump file in two users.

Is it possible?

Comment: What sort of dump file do you "have with you"? Is it created by Data Pump Export (expdp) or the old fashioned Export (exp)?

Comment: @colin-t-hart I have a .dmp file with me

Comment: .dmp says nothing about the format of the dump file.

Answer (score 1):

If your dump has been created with `exp` then you may use `imp` for importing it. If you exported schema `USERA` and want to import these objects in schema `USERB`, then use command:

```
imp user/password@sid FROMUSER=USERA TOUSER=USERB FILE=yourfile.dmp
```

you may get more example of `imp` on the [Import Export FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ). You may import your dump two times using different `USERB`.

Comment: impdp user/password DUMPFILE=file_name directory=dir LOGFILE=test.log REMAP_SCHEMA=USERA:USERB TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND

USER A is the existing user USER B is the new user

Answer (score 0):

`impdp user/password DUMPFILE=file_name directory=dir LOGFILE=test.log REMAP_SCHEMA=USERA:USERB TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND`

This will solve the issue.

USER A is the existing user USER B is the new user